# MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create and on update

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-error-1293

I want to define table which will have 2 TIMESTAMP fields, someting like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `msgs` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `msg` VARCHAR(256),
    `ts_create` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ts_update` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

How to do this avoiding error:

```
ERROR 1293 (HY000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Point is to keep desired behavior of `ts_create` and `ts_update` in table schema.

Comment: I believe the error is clear and what you seek is the alternative way to use do the same thing like current_timestamp

Comment: Use recent version of MySQL(5.6.5+), that should work for you!

Comment: as per current documentation this syntax should be working:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Guess this is a old post but actually i guess mysql supports 2 TIMESTAMP in its recent editions mysql 5.6.25 thats what im using as of now.

Answer (score 8):

i think it is possible by using below technique

```
`ts_create` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`ts_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not valid timestamp, though mysql will allow, many other databases do not allow '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as default to timestamp datatype, so at certain time, if you are migrating away from mysql, this would be painful.

Comment: This is actually painful also in MySQL, you shouldn't use zeros to initialise a timestamp or date/time column.

Comment: Whether zeroes are allowed as a valid timestamp depends on the current SQL mode. Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Answer (score 5):

You are using older MySql version. Update your myqsl to 5.6.5+ it will work.

Comment: The question was from 2011, MySQL 5 was brand new then.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two TIMESTAMP column with the same default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on your table. Please refer to this link: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe want ts_create as datetime (so rename -> dt_create) and only ts_update as timestamp? This will ensure it remains unchanging once set.

My understanding is that datetime is for manually-controlled values, and timestamp's a bit "special" in that MySQL will maintain it for you. In this case, datetime is therefore a good choice for ts_create.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you don't need to have the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on your ts_update: if it is empty, then it is not updated, so your 'last update' is the ts_create.

Comment: you can't have a ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP if you have another field with TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT

Comment: I know. But the question was not "why does this happen", but "how can I avoid it". This answers that question I believe better then "change the datatypes and make a trigger".

Answer (score 0):

This is the tiny limitation of Mysql in older version , actually after version 5.6 and later multiple timestamps works...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
    `ts_create` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ts_update` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP