# Date,time resets every time i use UPDATE

Tags: php, date, updates, reset

Date, time resets every time i use UPDATE,

**page1**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (time) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

**page2** (not connected with page1)

```
echo $row['time'];
```

and after i use

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE tablica SET views = views+1 WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
```

date and time resets to current date and time
and if i delete UPDATE code everything is fine, 
type is timestamp, 
how to stop reseting date and time?

Comment: Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output?

Comment: Store the time in session

Comment: Set the type to datetime instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table field is defined as `timestamp`, then it'll update automatically when record is changed / updated.

Read more about timestamps and issues here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html

[MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create and on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update)

Comment: man...everybody say timestamp is the best so i put it didnt,know this is part of it, anyway, tnx!

Comment: Timestamp is useful in some cases, but to really use it you first need to understand every aspect of it in MySQL DB. Simplest usage is for `last_time_updated` type of fields, but timestamp can be used in other cases too. Note, that it's hard (MySQL issues) to use more than one timestamp field in table.