# confusion between DateTime and TimeStamp in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am using mysql, and have four fields in all tables,

```
created_by varchar(128)
created_on timestamp default current_timestamp
updated_by varchar(128)
updated_on timestamp default current_timestamp
```

I have read on different answers on stack overflow that every time when some operation is performed on a table row, the field whose default value is `current_timestamp` is automatically updated. But I want to `created_on` to automatically insert `current_timestamp` when a new record updated, and when this record updated after some time, only updated_by field automatically updated to `current_timestamp` not the `created_by`.

Comment: [RTM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), you can have only 1 field with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` prior to 5.6. Not sure why, but you'll either have to set the `updated` or `created` value manually, or create a trigger (which is, IMO, ugly).

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having both a Created and Last Updated timestamp columns in MySQL 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267658/having-both-a-created-and-last-updated-timestamp-columns-in-mysql-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

```
created_by varchar(128)
created_on timestamp default current_timestamp
updated_by varchar(128)
updated_on timestamp default current_timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

MORE INFO:: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: This will only work if OP is running mysql 5.6 or higher, though

Comment: are you sure ? should be available since 5.0

Comment: Check the [5.5 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html): _"It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column"_. Voted to close this question as duplicate BTW(cf third comment below the question)

Answer (score 0):

I use this structure:

```
created_by varchar(128)
created_on timestamp  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
updated_by varchar(128)
updated_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

During first time `INSERT INTO` use `NOW()` for `created_on`. After that modifying the row will always automatically update the `updated_on` field. No need to touch the `TIMESTAMP` columns at all for `UPDATE` statements. (Note: The timestamp will be updated only if something is really updated. IE. Updating the columns with existing values doesn't modify anything so the timestamp is not updated.)