# keep previous timestamp in mysql on update

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I don't want to update my timestamp field when update. I need to keep previous datetime in that field. But its updating automatically even I tried following

```
$data = array(
                'start_time' => $start,//previous datetime
                'user_id' => $agent_id,
                ....
            );
            $this->db->where('id', $chat_id)->update('chat_state', $data );
```

When I leave `$start` or force with previous datetime. Not work in both cases. Its updating with `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` in both cases

whats wrong here??

Comment: that is either baked into the [schema](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4897002) or codeigniter functionality I believe

Comment: In database `start_time` field default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and unremovable

Comment: IS that from a database, or a session?  if a database, check how the item has the time stamp set.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your mysql server using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), to check your table's schema, by running the following queries:

```
USE mydatabase;    
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

I bet you'll see something like *ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP* associated with your *start_time* field.

Note that, relying on DBMS to auto-update values is not a good practice; It gives you surprises, and you end up spending hours to figure out the issue.

Let's **remove the "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" clause**, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY start_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This should solve the problem.

Read more about [TIMESTAMP's behaviors in different situations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Select exist value (`start_time`)
2. Update exist value to new field
3. insert new value

**01 Select current value in db**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT start_time FROM chat_state WHERE user_id = $chat_id");
$result = $query->result_array();
```

**02 Update exist value**

```
$data = array(
    'old_time' => $result[0]['start_time'] // move start_time to new field 
);
$this->db->where('id', $chat_id)->update('chat_state', $data );
```

**03 insert new value**

```
$data = array(
    'start_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),     // new Time stamp
    'user_id' => $agent_id
);
$this->db->where('id', $chat_id)->update('chat_state', $data );
```

Comment: thanks for effort. this is what i have done in my question. however it was work. problem was in my code

Comment: @RejoanulAlam happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have the column type as DATETIME; you need to change the type to TIMESTAMP and default null. It will not be updated automatically.

Then, while inserting the data

```
'start_time'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

And when you want to print it in view

```
date('d-M-y', strtotime($record['start_time']));
```