# Invalid default value for 'created', but using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I'm using the Sequel Pro app to work with my db.

Using Mysql 5.7.

I have the following table structure. When I attempt to reorder the 'created' table column, I get an error from mysql "Invalid default value for 'created'.

I have no rows in the `materials` table when attempting the reorder.

From everything I've read, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the correct default value.

```
CREATE TABLE `materials` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My goal is to have the `created` column be automatically filled when the row is added. `modified` will automatically update to the current time when changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Here is a post related to your question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update)

Comment: @Srini The post you linked to doesn't answer my issue. In fact, in a comment as recent as February of this year, it should be valid. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35426865/68788

Answer (score 3):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is only acceptable on TIMESTAMP fields. DATETIME fields must be left either with a null default value, or no default value at all - default values must be a constant value, not the result of an expression.

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

You can work around this by setting a post-insert trigger on the table to fill in a "now" value on any new records.

refer :[Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded)