# Error : datetime column Incorrect datetime value: ''

Tags: php, mysql

I have datetime column(test_date) with default value set to current_timestamp

but when Update the table it shows

> Error in Updation Query
>   Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'test_date' at row 1

I even changed the column type to timestamp but still it throws the same error

> Error in Insertion Query 
>   insert into tbl_testimonials(test_title,test_image,test_content,test_date,status) values('hi','','this is checking','', 'Y')
>   Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'test_date' at row 1

My question is different : the question in [MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create and on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update) discuss about having to timestamp values in the same table and the error is

> ERROR 1293 (HY000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

But I have a single column with timestamp value and my error is

> Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'test_date' at row 1

So I think my question is different

Please help

Comment: set default value to current_timestamp

Comment: Show us your update statement please.

Comment: @scriptkiddie Can you show your update query?

Comment: @S.I. thx for the lookup

Comment: @Milan Gupta bro I have updated my question with the query bro with new value

Comment: @S.I bro read my question please, I have already set the default value to current_timestamp in phpmyadmin....

Comment: Check what you trying to insert in datetime column.

Comment: @S.I. I am not inserting anything bro, I just want my mysql server to assign the current_timestamp if it's empty

Comment: @scriptkiddie If you want mysql to do it for you then don't include test_date in your key values. So it should go something like `tbl_testimonials(test_title,test_image,test_content,status) values('hi','','this is checking', 'Y')`

Comment: @Milan Gupta thanks bro what about null?

Comment: please see http://i.imgur.com/1u0CBnv.jpg

Comment: @Milan Gupta Thank you bro it worked. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as an answer and upvote it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want mysql to do it for you then don't include test_date in your key values. So it should go something like below:

```
tbl_testimonials  
(test_title,test_image,test_content,status) values  
('hi','','this is checking', 'Y')
```