# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - How to check if a row has been updated then trigger a column to insert modified date?

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I insert my data using `INSERT INTO SELECT` then I have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` like this:

```
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
  first_name = COALESCE(eb.first_name, employee.first_name), 
  middle_name = COALESCE(eb.middle_name, employee.middle_name), 
  last_name=COALESCE(eb.last_name, employee.last_name), 
  nickname=COALESCE(eb.nickname, employee.nickname), 
  gender=COALESCE(eb.gender, employee.gender), 
  address=COALESCE(eb.address, employee.address), 
  mobile=COALESCE(eb.mobile, employee.mobile),
  birthdate=COALESCE(eb.birthdate, employee.birthdate), 
  status=COALESCE(eb.status, employee.status), 
  tr_email=COALESCE(eb.tr_email, employee.tr_email),
  position_id = COALESCE(position.id, employee.tr_email);
```

Now on the same table, there's a column `modified_date`, that I need to also update the value(insert the current date) when any column above gets updated. Is there a solution without creating a new table or some sort to compare the old values to the new one? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of points. If you are in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` section, you can say that you are doing an update and not an insert, so you could just add the mod to `modified_date` as part these other column updates

Comment: DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns may have an option ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. It will be updated automatically, without any additional code.

Comment: Or there is a way of creating a column that will automatically be updated with the current date when an update happens https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876096/2310830

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess I'm okay now with @Akina's solution.  I used ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.